# Create project with expo - React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I tried create a new project with expo, but I follow steps of expo page.
- Install Node.js
- npm install expo-cli --global
- expo init my-new-project
- cd my-new-project
- expo start

And when is open Expo DevTools in http://localhost:19002 and appear

```
- Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.

- Successfully ran `adb reverse`. Localhost URLs should work on the connected Android device.

- Tunnel ready.
```

I scan QR, or press run on Android device, this error appears:

```
Couldn't start project on Android: Cannot read property 'readConfigJsonAsync' of undefined
```

What happen!!?

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/822

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Just roll back expo cli to version 2.21.2:**

> npm install -g expo-cli@2.21.2

Also happened to me after making updates on Yarn, NPM and Expo CLI.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But I feel bad that I can not use version 3.

Comment: I can't install v2.21.2, i have v2.20.1, i try to uninstall and install againt, it isn't work...

Answer (score 1):

first install expo `npm install -g expo-cli`

then run this command for create app in react-native with expo `expo init AppName`

after go to your app `cd  Appname` then run expo app command `npm start`

Comment: the expo SDK requires expo run.